# Missing Join Predicate Warning

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, profiler

I'm running a SQL Server 2005 trace using profiler.  I'm seeing some missing join predicate warnings, but I can't determine where its occurring with the data they are giving me.  All I have is the transactionID.  Any way to find out what object is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the profiler trace data, it will be due to the query run just before it.